# Android - Navigation drawer with menu icon instead of back button

Tags: java, android

I'm starting learning android and when I created my app I chose the Navigation Drawer template and here is the problem:

1) Even though I'm at the homepage the back button is displayed, and it opens the menu

2) I'd like to have a menu icon in every single page and let the hardware back button handle the intent history

So basically I'd like to know how to change back button icon to menu icon.

code: (onCreateOptionsMenu)

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I can show/hide the back button but I can't figure out where it's calling the icon itself

Sorry if it's a silly question but I didn't find good answers to this (on ly this link: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: are you talking about the actionbar or toolbar

Comment: I'm talking about action bar =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you will find a method where i do some customization over my actionBar try to use some of it :) , also you will need to make your own custom action bar xml file

```
    private void setCustomActionBar() {

    ActionBar mActionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_main_actionbar, null);

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    actionBarTitle = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title_tv);
    actionBarHomeBtn = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_app_icon);
    actionBarSyncBtn = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_sync_btn);
    actionBarSearchBtn = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_search_btn);
    actionBarHomeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }
    });

    actionBarSyncBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    actionBarSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this code part of a open source project? May I take a look to see how it's being used? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to take a deep look to understand how everything works :)